# local web server configuration error

Tags: apache2, webserver, localhost

Localhost won't load. I guess i have messed up some config file.[apachestatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Bfp.png)

'''error.log
[Sun Apr 05 13:08:09.331979 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1143] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 05 13:08:09.331999 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1143] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
'''
'''error.log.1
[Fri Apr 03 15:08:18.636167 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1146] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 03 15:08:18.636197 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1146] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 03 20:02:01.131782 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1146] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 04 20:22:24.433336 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1181] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 04 20:22:24.445314 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1181] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 04 21:47:37.436170 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1181] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Apr 05 12:12:21.416753 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1143] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 05 12:12:21.449980 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1143] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Apr 05 13:08:09.301671 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1143] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2409:4043:496:1f97:86:a5a8:887d:c759. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
'''

Comment: What's in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: [Tue Mar 31 16:05:46.212116 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1167] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 16:05:46.212144 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1167] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 31 18:53:01.192762 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1167] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 31 18:53:01.242842 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32413] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 18:53:01.242886 2020] [core:notice] [pid 32413] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Tue Mar 31 18:53:01.242886 2020] [core:notice] [pid 32413] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 31 19:01:03.584650 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32413] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 31 19:01:03.645944 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32597] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 19:01:03.645991 2020] [core:notice] [pid 32597] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 31 19:07:43.449904 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32597] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: [Tue Mar 31 19:07:43.510838 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32709] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 19:07:43.510881 2020] [core:notice] [pid 32709] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 31 21:14:56.265597 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32709] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 01 15:55:39.103723 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1134] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 01 15:55:39.179212 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1134] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: There are a 2-3 error logs

Comment: Please add this output to your question and format it as code. It's hardly readable like this, and comments are not always preserved.